# Windows 10 fails to install generic drivers for USB microphone

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, microphone

I recently purchased a RØDE NT-USB microphone which uses generic USB Audio drivers and claims to work out of the box with both OSX and Windows. On OSX I had no issues but on Windows I ran into an issue with the driver not installing.

[image]

When opening the device manager I see that the microphone has a yellow triangle on it and it does not show up under playback or recording devices. Right clicking on the microphone in the device manager and then clicking 'Update drivers' shows an error that says drivers could not be installed, see below:

[image]

I am using an ROG STRIX Z270E motherboard. I have tried all of the USB ports that are available with the same result. When switching the USB ports I have tried uninstalling the device and restarted the computer numerous times in many different combinations. Still I am left with the same result.

**What can I do to try to fix the driver issue with a generic USB microphone when drivers fail to install?**

I appreciate the help!

**Edit:** adding install log from `C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log`

```
>>>  [Device Install (DiShowUpdateDevice) - USB\VID_19F7&PID_0003&MI_00\6&1D13485A&1&0000]
>>>  Section start 2017/11/30 08:49:10.027
      cmd: "C:\Windows\system32\mmc.exe" C:\Windows\system32\devmgmt.msc
     dvi: {DIF_UPDATEDRIVER_UI} 08:49:10.028
     dvi:      Default installer: Enter 08:49:10.029
     dvi:      Default installer: Exit
     dvi: {DIF_UPDATEDRIVER_UI - exit(0xe000020e)} 08:49:10.029
     ndv: {Update Driver Software Wizard - USB\VID_19F7&PID_0003&MI_00\6&1D13485A&1&0000}
     ndv:      Search options: 0x00000203
     ndv:      Searching currently installed INF
     dvi:      {Build Driver List} 08:49:11.328
     dvi:           Searching for hardware ID(s):
     dvi:                usb\vid_19f7&pid_0003&rev_0100&mi_00
     dvi:                usb\vid_19f7&pid_0003&mi_00
     dvi:           Searching for compatible ID(s):
     dvi:                usb\class_01&subclass_01&prot_00
     dvi:                usb\class_01&subclass_01
     dvi:                usb\class_01
     dvi:      {Build Driver List - exit(0x00000000)} 08:49:11.331
     ndv:      Searching default INF path
     dvi:      {Build Driver List} 08:49:11.332
     dvi:           Searching for hardware ID(s):
     dvi:                usb\vid_19f7&pid_0003&rev_0100&mi_00
     dvi:                usb\vid_19f7&pid_0003&mi_00
     dvi:           Searching for compatible ID(s):
     dvi:                usb\class_01&subclass_01&prot_00
     dvi:                usb\class_01&subclass_01
     dvi:                usb\class_01
     dvi:           Created Driver Node:
     dvi:                HardwareID   - USB\CLASS_01
     dvi:                InfName      - C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\wdma_usb.inf_amd64_48d65adf692e432c\wdma_usb.inf
     dvi:                DevDesc      - USB Audio Device
     dvi:                Section      - USBAudio
     dvi:                Rank         - 0x00ff2002
     dvi:                Signer Score - INBOX
     dvi:                DrvDate      - 09/28/2017
     dvi:                Version      - 10.0.16299.15
     dvi:      {Build Driver List - exit(0x00000000)} 08:49:11.450
     dvi:      {DIF_SELECTBESTCOMPATDRV} 08:49:21.001
     dvi:           Using exported function 'MediaClassInstaller' in module 'C:\Windows\system32\mmci.dll'.
     dvi:           Class installer == mmci.dll,MediaClassInstaller
     dvi:           Class installer: Enter 08:49:21.014
     dvi:           Class installer: Exit
     dvi:           Default installer: Enter 08:49:21.014
     dvi:                {Select Best Driver}
     dvi:                     Class GUID of device changed to: {4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}.
     dvi:                     {DIF_DESTROYPRIVATEDATA} 08:49:21.015
     dvi:                          Class installer: Enter 08:49:21.015
     dvi:                          Class installer: Exit
     dvi:                          Default installer: Enter 08:49:21.016
     dvi:                          Default installer: Exit
     dvi:                     {DIF_DESTROYPRIVATEDATA - exit(0xe000020e)} 08:49:21.016
     dvi:                     Selected Driver:
     dvi:                          Description - USB Audio Device
     dvi:                          InfFile     - c:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\wdma_usb.inf_amd64_48d65adf692e432c\wdma_usb.inf
     dvi:                          Section     - USBAudio
     dvi:                {Select Best Driver - exit(0x00000000)}
     dvi:           Default installer: Exit
     dvi:      {DIF_SELECTBESTCOMPATDRV - exit(0x00000000)} 08:49:21.018
     sto:      {Setup Import Driver Package: C:\Windows\INF\wdma_usb.inf} 08:49:21.035
     sto:           Driver package already imported as 'wdma_usb.inf'.
     sto:      {Setup Import Driver Package - exit (0x00000000)} 08:49:21.058
     dvi:      Searching for hardware ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\vid_19f7&pid_0003&rev_0100&mi_00
     dvi:           usb\vid_19f7&pid_0003&mi_00
     dvi:      Searching for compatible ID(s):
     dvi:           usb\class_01&subclass_01&prot_00
     dvi:           usb\class_01&subclass_01
     dvi:           usb\class_01
     dvi:      Class GUID of device changed to: {4d36e96c-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}.
     ump:      Installation will be processed asynchronously
!!!  ndv:      Device install failed for device.
!!!  ndv:      Error 0xe0000246: One of the installers for this device cannot perform the installation at this time.
     ndv:      Installing NULL driver.
     ump:      Installation will be processed asynchronously
```

Comment: One thought for troubleshooting: while it may be a generic error, it points to an installer either not having permissions or a device blocking install. have you tried disabling all other audio devices (and rebooting) prior to attempting installation? Have you checked for any audio devices that may have the "exclusive mode" set? Have you checked Event Viewer to see if there are any indicators what installer failed? Is there an installer package you can run manually as admin (probably covered when going in via device manager)

Comment: look in the file **C:\Windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log** which action fails and which error code is shown

Comment: Thank you so much for the help but none of the above solutions seem to get me anywhere. Somehow I made things worse and now my headset is not finding a driver either and Geforce experience wont install. I will probably do a reinstall of windows as this is a fairly new install anyways. I added the log output to my question.

Comment: 0xe0000246 = ERROR_DEVICE_INSTALLER_NOT_READY